# Why is my flag weight displayed with decimals

Tags: bug, flagging

My flag weight is displayed with decimals. Currently it reads "510.0000" both on my [user page](https://askubuntu.com/users/19490/) for the main site and on my flagging summary page for the main site (no sense in linking the latter since they seem to be private). The following image shows how it currently looks on my user page:

[image: Flag weight with decimals]

I have only noticed this behavior for my current flag weight. Am I right in assuming that it's a bug?

Comment: Flag weight has since [been removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119715/what-happened-to-flag-weight) and simply replaced with a useful flag count. As such, this may be too localized now.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 Feel free to flag it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug.

If your flag weight reaches 500, the calculation turns from linear to asymptotic, eventually reaching 749.99999 (or maybe 750, if you're lucky).

See also: [What is flag weight?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight/80178#80178)

Maybe it should be rounded, but this display gives you an idea of what you're heading for, if you keep raising great flags :)

Comment: If I check out any other use with the [Deputy badge](http://askubuntu.com/badges/75/deputy) their flag weight is expressed *without* decimals. Why is that?

Comment: It seems like a (sensible) design decision to round the flag weight of *other* users for you.